# cant open programs with ".lnk" extension using subprocess.call function

Tags: python, subprocess

it seems subprocess.call function just can be used for the files with '.exe' extension.

This is the code i tried for Firefox.lnk in which this is the same code i tried for a git program that has '.exe' extension and worked without error.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('C:/users/m.m/Desktop/Programs/Firefox')
```

This is the error I get with `Firefox.lnk` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/m.m/PycharmProjects/untitled5/pros.py", line 2, in <module>
subprocess.call('C:/users/m.m/Desktop/Programs/Firefox.lnk')
File 
"C:\Users\m.m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", 
line 323, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File 
"C:\Users\m.m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", 
line 775, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File 
"C:\Users\m.m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", 
line 1178, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

`Firefox` (**Without extension**) gives me `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.

when i try the code without extension for those programs with '.exe' extension i have no problem but with any program without '.exe' extension i get error... just like firefox that has '.lnk' extension.

Comment: Read Microsoft docs about "start" command

Comment: @MichaelButscher, could you please include a link ?

Comment: Sorry, forget it. There is "os.startfile()" for this in Python's standard library.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, really appreciate it , you're last comment solved my problem immediately.So you could post it as an answer that I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process `.lnk` files on Windows there is `os.startfile()` (Windows only) in the standard library.

If you want to add parameters to the command, you can also use the [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command. It is a builtin command (no `start.exe`) therefore a shell is needed to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#security-considerations) to make this work!

```py
lnk_path = 'C:/users/m.m/Desktop/Programs/Firefox.lnk'
subprocess.call(lnk_path, shell=True)
```